# Pageview counter increment +3 (+2 sometimes) at 1st page-call, then +1, why?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

A strange issues on my *pageview script counter* (php code) is happening.
When I visit a page of my website using firefox browser, **the increment of the pageview is equal to +3** (from 9 to 12 for instance). If I reload the page, the increment is right and equal at +1.

With Opera browser most of times happen that the increment is +2 for the first pagecall and +1 for following page reload.
With Chrome most of times the increment is +3 for first call and +1 for following reload.

The query is very simple:

```
// update viewtimes
$momento = date("Y-m-d G:i:s", time()); 
$queryUpdateVisite = " 
UPDATE projects SET 
lastviewtime = '$momento', 
viewtimes = viewtimes+1 
WHERE id='$dati[id]' ";
if (mysqli_query($db, $queryUpdateVisite)) {
$messaggioUpdateVisite = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">ok</div>";
} else {
$messaggioUpdateVisite= "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">ERROR</div>";
echo "$messaggioUpdateVisite\n";
}
```

How to fix it?

edit: even with: WHERE id= $dati[id] the behaviour is the same.

Make a try by open: http://www.fabiodisconzi.com/open-h2020/per-country/it/universita+degli+studi+di+sassari/index.html and checking the "view" column try to visit some projects. Even with Edge browser the issue persists.

Comment: Maybe the page is pre-loaded by the browser? (see http://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/) 

Furthermore, you could use the SQL NOW() function for the datetime, so:
 `lastviewtime = NOW()`

Comment: UPDATE!
**The problem is caused by the google adsense script**. Why? What is the process that cause the triple or double counting? I have just try to remove the adsense code and the pageview counter works fine.

Comment: It should be a problem of the ASYNC mode of adsense network.

Comment: Can it be an issue of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
$queryUpdateVisite = "UPDATE projects SET lastviewtime = '$momento', viewtimes = viewtimes+1 WHERE id= $dati[id]";
```

`id` is written in single quotation. If your `id` is `number` then write it as it is.

Comment: I try this modification but the issue persists. Many thanks.

Comment: Any idea? Could be a wrong setting of the web-server?